# Razor-section for document.ready handling missing intellisense

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my master `_Layout.cshtml` I have the following markup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        @RenderSection("documentReady");
    });
</script>
```

To have all my code which should run after pages has been loaded organized together.

I a concrete `View` I have then:

```
@section documentReady
{
    // some javascript-code here
}
```

The problem is, that I don't have any `javascript` intellisense-support inside the `section`.

If I write

```
@section documentReady
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // some javascript-code here
    </script>
}
```

instead, I have intellisense. But at rendering it throws me an exception:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

as of it renders to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        <script type="text/javascript"> // <-- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

What is the best way to get around this?
Are there any good examples how to use sections for this purpose or how to organize view-based `javascript` in MVC at all?

I've also tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @section documentReady
    {
        // some javascript-code here
    }
</script>
```

which is also not giving me any intellisense (but will at least render to `valid HTML/javascript`).

Comment: Your layout should just have `@RenderSection("documentReady");` (not wrapped in `<script>` tags or the `$(function()` (note by convention its `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`

Comment: So, there is no simple way to have my `onReady`-code written per `View` without repeating the `<script>$(function(){...});</script>` part?
And what about partial views? How should this be done (as of partials do not have any `_Layout` specified)?

Comment: Scripts should never be in partials (only in the main view or layout

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have any good examples on how to use `scripts` inside partials or how to work around this? In my application I do use partials (loaded via ajax) and I don't know how to handle `javascript` stuff properly (as I want to have the code in the file it is executed and not in the parent which does not know about the partial inside itself).